# WebClient ExchangeFilterFunction unable to add header java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ReadOnlyHttpHeaders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to add a simple ExchangeFilterFunction to a WebClient request. However, I am seeing the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.add(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:84)
    at com.ecs.springframework.reactive.web.filter.AddHeaderExchangeFilter.filter(AddHeaderExchangeFilter.java:24)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$apply$2(ExchangeFilterFunction.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:319)
    at com.ecs.springframework.reactive.web.filter.AddHeaderExchangeFilterTest.whenExchangeFilterFunctionInjectedIntoWebClient_thenWebClientShouldPropagate(AddHeaderExchangeFilterTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at
```

ExchangeFilterFunction

```
    public class AddHeaderExchangeFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

      @Override
      public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

        ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest.create(request.method(), request.url()).build();
        newRequest.headers().add("EFF-TEST-HEADER", "EFF-TEST-VALUE");
        return next.exchange(newRequest);
      }
    }
```

```
        WebClient webTestClient = WebClient.builder().filter(new AddHeaderExchangeFilter()).build();

    webTestClient.get().uri("http://httpbin.org/get").exchange();
```

I am relatively new to WebFlux so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the headers when you creating `newRequest`:

```java
    public class AddHeaderExchangeFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {
        @Override
        public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

            ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
                                                    .header("EFF-TEST-HEADER", "EFF-TEST-VALUE")
                                                    .build();
            return next.exchange(newRequest);
        }
    }
```

The reason for your current behavior is that `ClientRequest.create` initiating new `DefaultClientRequestBuilder`.
You can see in the [Spring's source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java#L187) that once you `build()` your request the builder building the request with read only headers, and therefore you can't add the headers after you built the `ClientRequest`.

Comment: `ClientRequest.from(request)` would be slightly better than `ClientRequest.create(request.method(), request.url())`